# Receive from specific offset with Qpid Proton + RabbitMQ Stream Queue (Core)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, qpid-proton

I want to implement a python based receiver app with Qpid proton library to consume messages from a RabbitMQ Stream Queue over AMQP 1.0. For a proper implementation I need to track the offset of consumed messages. When restarting the receiver I want to continue receiving from the last consumed offset instead of the lastest messages.

How can I pass the offset number to the proton receiver so that it only reads from that offset? I don't find related documentation about any approach achieving this.

with the following attempts, no offset filtering was applied:
`receiver.source.filter.put_dict({'x-stream-offset': ulong(1000)'}`
`receiver.source.filter.put_dict({'rabbitmq:stream-offset-spec': ulong(1000)'}`
`event.container.create_receiver(conn, "examples", options=Selector(u"x-stream-offset = '1000'"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to import symbol and use `symbol("rabbitmq:stream-offset-spec")`:

sample extract:

```py
from proton import symbol
from proton.reactor import Filter

offset = 123

offset_filter = Filter(filter_set={symbol("rabbitmq:stream-offset-spec"): ulong(int(offset))})
receiver = conn.create_receiver(address=self.address, options=offset_filter)
```